# Adding double quotes to string in R

Tags: r, string-concatenation

How can I add double quotes to a string taken from a vector in R?

I tried using paste but it doesn't work very well

```
kg_name=paste("\"",k_groups[i,],"\"")
```

lets say the value of k_groups[i,] is blah, so I'm looking for this result

```
"blah"
```

but the result is

```
"\" blah \""
```

Comment: If you do `paste0`, you will get rid of the spaces between the quotes and your string. The `shQuote` is used for escaping a command passed to a shell. It should not be used for just simple quoting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `shQuote`

```
shQuote("blah")
# [1] "\"blah\""
```

The above will work on Windows.  Use `shQuote("blah", "cmd")` if you need it to work the same way giving double quotes on all operating systems.

Comment: Almost, the problem is that I need exactly "blah" as a result not "\"blah\"". I mean just add normal quotes to blah.

Comment: That is what it does.  The backslashes are not part of the string.  Try `strsplit(shQuote("blah"), "")` to see the individual characters or `nchar(shQuote("blah"))` -- the count shows that there are only 6 characters.  If you want to display a string containing quotes without seeing the backslashes try `cat(shQuote("blah"), "\n")` .

Comment: I am trying this way...but my prob is output is `'blah'` not `"blah"`. I need the same result. Is there any other way.

Comment: Read `?shQuote`

Comment: `shQuote`: "Quote a string to be passed to an operating system shell." That's not it.

Comment: `message("\"x\"")` gives `"x"` but `paste0("\""x\"")` gives `"\"x\""` .. but it is actually just a question of display!! `sprintf("\"%s\"", "hello")` gives `\"hello\"` (apparently) but actually (and correctly) `"hello"` when printed via `message()`. Nice.