# Run cmd command from within R

Tags: r, command-line

I want to trigger/run a certain cmd command from within R. I found the functions `system`, `system2` and `shell`, but am a bit lost on how to exactly use them.

So if I would do it directly in Windows, I'd open the cmd and then run the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\LatentGOLD6.0\lg60" "C:\Users\USER\myfile.lgs" /b /o "C:\Users\USER\myfile.html" /h
```

However, I struggle with how and where I'd specify such a command in R so that it runs the thing. All of the mentioend functions above require a character string, but since I need to pass the paths with quotes, I'm actually not sure how I can glue all of this together.

Any ideas?

So here's my current code:

```
program_path <- "C:\Program Files\LatentGOLD6.0\lg60"
lgs_path     <- "C:\Users\USER\myfile.lgs"
out_path     <- "C:\Users\USER\myfile.html"

batchline <- paste0(program_path, " ", lgs_path, " /b /o ", out_path, " /h")

system(batchline)
system2(batchline)
```

Alternative also doesn't work: `batchline <- paste0("'", program_path, "'", " ", "'", lgs_path, "'", " /b /o ", "'", out_path, "'", " /h")`

Comment: Wrap in `'` or escape quotes with `\"`.

Comment: ok thanks. But i'm still getting e.g. an error 127 if I wrap all file path into single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `r"{...}"` if there are backslashes within the literal string as we do here or else double each backslash (see `?Quotes`) or in some cases using forward slash in place of backslash will work. Then use `sprintf` to generate `batchline`.

```
program_path <- r"{C:\Program Files\LatentGOLD6.0\lg60}"
lgs_path     <- r"{C:\Users\USER\myfile.lgs}"
out_path     <- r"{C:\Users\USER\myfile.html}"

batchline <- sprintf("%s %s /b /o %s /h", program_path, lgs_path, out_path)
```

or if you want to surround each path with quotes then replace last line with:

```
batchline <- sprintf('"%s" "%s" /b /o "%s" /h', program_path, lgs_path, out_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: updated bug where I initially used forward slashes.

ok, found a solution with the help of this here: [Adding double quotes to string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490802/adding-double-quotes-to-string-in-r), i.e. wrapping the file paths into `shQuote` works.

```
program_path <- normalizePath("C:/Program Files/LatentGOLD6.0/lg60")
lgs_path     <- normalizePath("C:/Users/USER/myfile.lgs")
out_path     <- normalizePath("C:/Users/USER/myfile.html")

batchline <- paste0(shQuote(program_path),
                    " ",
                    shQuote(lgs_path),
                    " /b /o ",
                    shQuote(out_path),
                    " /h")

system(batchline)
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the `normalizePath` part.

Comment: Interesting. It does, though, for me.

Comment: If you enter `"C:\Users\USER\myfile.html"`  R will produce the error message `Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"`

Comment: Yes, I now see my problem. It's the forward vs. backwards slash. I missed that part!

Comment: Updated my post to reflect the corrected code.